# thread safe function pointer gsl monte carlo integration

Tags: c++, thread-safety, function-pointers, gsl

I want to use the gsl monte carlo integration library and I'm currently running into thread safety problems which I could not resolve so far.

I have a static function **gsl_func_wrapper**, that wraps that has the correct type required by gsl (non-member function pointer). That is passed to the gsl monte carlo integrator inside the **Integral** member function.

```
class IntegralStrategyGSL2D: public IntegralStrategy2D {
  static Model2D *current_model;

  const gsl_rng_type *T;
  gsl_rng *r;
  gsl_monte_vegas_state *s;
  size_t calls;
  size_t maxcalls;

  static double gsl_func_wrapper(double *x, size_t dim, void *params) {
    return current_model->eval(x);
  }
...
}

IntegralStrategyGSL2D::IntegralStrategyGSL2D() :
    T(gsl_rng_default) {
  calls = 500;    // keep calls low at first
  maxcalls = 100000;
  gsl_rng_env_setup();
  r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);
  s = gsl_monte_vegas_alloc(2);
}

double IntegralStrategyGSL2D::Integral(Model2D *model2d, double xlow,
    double xhigh, double ylow, double yhigh, double precision) {
  current_model = model2d;
  double result, error;

  double xl[2] = { xlow, ylow };
  double xu[2] = { xhigh, yhigh }

  gsl_monte_function G = { &gsl_func_wrapper, 2, 0 };

  gsl_monte_vegas_init(s);

  while (true) {
    gsl_monte_vegas_integrate(&G, xl, xu, 2, calls, r, s, &result, &error);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

All of this works if I run with 1 thread, and i get nan integral once in a while if I use more than one thread. Since gsl requires this non-member function pointer I don't really see right now how I can make this thread safe... Can someone point me in the right direction? Thx

**Edit:** I added the eval function that will be called by the gsl_func_wrapper.

```
double GaussianModel2D::eval(const double *x) const {
  // see wikipedia definition

  double normalization = 1.0
        / (2.0 * M_PI * gauss_sigma_var1->getValue()
                * gauss_sigma_var2->getValue()
                * sqrt(1 - pow(gauss_rho->getValue(), 2.0)));

  double exp_value = exp(
        -(pow(x[0] - gauss_mean_var1->getValue(), 2.0)
                / pow(gauss_sigma_var1->getValue(), 2.0)
                + pow(x[1] - gauss_mean_var2->getValue(), 2.0)
                        / pow(gauss_sigma_var2->getValue(), 2.0)
                + 2.0 * gauss_rho->getValue()
                        * (x[0] - gauss_mean_var1->getValue())
                        * (x[1] - gauss_mean_var2->getValue())
                        / (gauss_sigma_var1->getValue()
                                * gauss_sigma_var2->getValue()))
                / (2.0 * (1 - pow(gauss_rho->getValue(), 2.0))));

  return gauss_amplitude->getValue() * normalization * exp_value;
}
```

**Edit2:**
I added the calls for the Integral function as requested by Mike. So below are the two relevant blocks of code that make the Integral call. I don't really understand why the thread_local keyword for current_model variable fixes the problem.. Event though the code is bit ugly, shouldn't the current_model variable always point to the same model2d pointer? So even if two threads may have conflicting writes the value thats written is always the same so it should not matter or?

```
double smearing_probability = divergence_model->Integral(int_range, 1e-4);

double Model2D::Integral(const std::vector<DataStructs::DimensionRange &ranges,
    double precision) {
    return integral_strategy->Integral(this, ranges[0].range_low,
        ranges[0].range_high, ranges[1].range_low, ranges[1].range_high,
        precision);
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `Model2D::eval`.

Comment: You could probably use classes as function pointers which avoids this problem but not well.

Comment: @Pete: Model2D::eval is a pure virtual function but for my case its a very complex function so I'm not sure if I should post all of this here... Is that relevant?

Comment: It's part of the code that gets executed in the callback, so, yes, it's relevant. But if it's very complex you should take some time to trim it so that it's the shortest you can get and still show the problem.

Comment: @Pete: I added the function that will be called in an edit. Its a cached function, so only the cached access will be acually called by the integrator. I think that should be all.

Comment: @David: You mean like a functor? I don't see how I can implement that though...

Comment: So `model_grid` has already been filled in with all the appropriate values? Then that doesn't look like it's the problem. When you change from single-threaded to multi-threaded, the most common source of errors is data races, i.e., one thread writing to some data while another thread reads or writes the same data. I don't see anything here that would lead to a data race, though.

Comment: Yeah exactly. The only thing that I cant really tell whats going on is that static function call.... All threads will call the same static gsl_func_wrapper() and same eval() function. Are multiple thread reads on the same memory thread safe?

Comment: It would be helpfull to see how `IntegralStrategyGSL2D::Integral` is called and especially, where the `model2d` parameter comes from. Also what are you doing with `gsl_monte_function G`?

Comment: There's no single piece of code anyone here could use to reproduce the problem, so all that people are doing here is guessing and pointing out isolated flaws, but they will never be able to fully explain your misconception. That's why the guidelines require you to extract a minimal example first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Integral` is called in the same thread, that executes `gsl_func_wrapper`, you can use [`thread_loca`l](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) instead of `static` as a storage class for `current_model`.

That will give you a separate `current_model` variable for each thread.

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work, I will test it bit more thoroughly tomorrow and give an update. Thanks a lot Mike.

Comment: Ok, so it just ran a bit longer than usual by chance before. It still gives me nan results for the integrals once in an while...

Comment: @steve: Then the problem is most likely not (only) in the code you have shown us. Please provide an [mcve](/help/mcve). You are talking about problems with multiple threads, but as it stands, it is completely unclear, where you spawn those threads and what data each thread is accessing

Comment: Ok, I get that... It's a bit difficult to extract only the pieces of to give you an mcve. Maybe I can get further with a simpler question: all threads evaluate the identical function since im only giving it a pointer right? So creating any local variable in that function can already introduce problems regarding thread safety or?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to figure out the problem. It was that the variables

`const gsl_rng_type *T;
gsl_rng *r;
gsl_monte_vegas_state *s;`

were all instance variables, hence used by all threads in the same way. If I create each of these within the Integral() function separately for each thread everything runs fine...